# Clicking "Annotate" in intellij gives warning "number of lines annotated by git is not equal to number of lines"

Tags: git, android-studio, intellij-idea, ide

When I try to see the side menu upon clicking "show annotate" this message appears only on this file. Other than that annotations work for all other files.

> number of lines annotated by git is not equal to number of lines in
> the file. **Check file encoding and line separators**

This problem occurs in Intellij. And in my case in Android Studio

Comment: So, what happened when you checked the file encoding and line separators, like it says to do?

Comment: @torek nothing happened. All pages work fine except this file

Comment: Is there a chance that you are editing this file outside of IDE? Would "Refresh" in Local Changes help?

Comment: Put that information into your question as well. How did you check the file encoding? What was the result of checking the file encoding? How did you check the line separators, and what was the result? You say "nothing happened" but that's uninformative: *something* must have happened, such as, the program you ran to check the file format said that the file format was _____ (fill in the blank).

Comment: This happened to me when I created a branch of the same name as another branch. issue-34 existed and then I created branch ISSUE-34. Android Studio was comparing my branch to the old issue-34 instead of the parent branch of the new ISSUE-34.

Answer (score 3):

WSL2, Windows 11, Goland GoLand 2022.1.2. Same problem.
IDE restart didn't help, what helped is to restart the WSL2 env:

```
wsl --shutdown ubuntu
```

Before restart you should close the IDE.

Answer (score 0):

I know it isn't the solution but I wasn't able find out the root of the problem
but I share what I did to get it working.

This happened to me after I hibernated my win 11 (WSL2 and docker) and the next day I tried to work.

After I restarted phpStorm it said, git was not even installed.

I did

- git reset hard and clean,
- reopened the project inside phpStorm, (after this it was still broken)
- restarted the computer

after all of this it started to work again.

Answer (score 0):

Was seeing this issue in both intelliJ and PyCharm at the same time
for the same file. I did not check if the issue persisted with any
other file (perhaps should have).

Though that putting the IDE in power save mode may have done it but
removing from power save mode did not work. Restarting the IDE by invalidating cache did not help either.

Then I realized that I had put that particular file to be assumed as
unchanged by running `git update-index --assume-unchanged <filename>`

Once I undid that by running `git update-index --no-assume-unchanged <filename>`, the warning went away - and the IDE showed all of the
lines properly annotated again.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

faced this issue in **GoLand** (sibling of IntelliJ) 
and, when opened the same project in **VSCode**, its working fine.

This gave a hint, that **something is wrong in .idea folder**, 
removed the .idea folder and opened the project again in GoLand, 
It Worked & annotation works well

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on PyCharm (Pro 2023.1.2), and running `File -> Repair IDE` did the trick.
The IDE will try a couple of things and will prompt you to check if things work on the bottom right corner.
For me the issue was the indexing, so it did its thing, and after a restart everything was working again.

Answer (score 0):

Got the same issue recently. My solution is to restart the IDE.